# fixing the script below. I am trying to run and was told i need a join statement. how do i add to the below?

Tags: sql

```
declare @s varchar(100)='(FILE';
select clientid
      ,ClientSort as ClientName
      ,'Y' as Enabled
      ,'N' as HIPPA
      ,matternum
      ,case
          when charindex(@s,[description])>0
          then left(cast([description] as varchar(max)),charindex(@s,[description])-1)
          else [description]
       end as MatterName
      ,'Y' as Enable
      ,'N' as HIPPA
,Status
   from matters
SELECT 
CASE
WHEN 'Family Law' then 'FL'
WHEN 'Workers Comp' then 'WC'
WHEN 'Criminal' then 'CR'
WHEN 'Corporate Business' then 'CB'
WHEN 'Personal Injury' then 'PI'
WHEN 'Litigation' then 'LI'
WHEN 'Estate Matters' then 'EM'
WHEN 'Miscellaneous' then 'MI'
WHEN 'Appeals' then 'AP'
WHEN 'Real Estate' then 'RE'
END as areaoflaw
 order by  Clientid
       ,matterid
 ;
```

Comment: You know that you need a `JOIN`, but did you do any research on how to do one?

Comment: Also, that last `CASE` statement makes no sense because you aren't even referencing a column for the value...

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a `join`.  The `case` goes in the `select`:

```
SELECT . . .,
       CASE ??
           WHEN 'Family Law' then 'FL'
           WHEN 'Workers Comp' then 'WC'
           WHEN 'Criminal' then 'CR'
           WHEN 'Corporate Business' then 'CB'
           WHEN 'Personal Injury' then 'PI'
           WHEN 'Litigation' then 'LI'
           WHEN 'Estate Matters' then 'EM'
           WHEN 'Miscellaneous' then 'MI'
           WHEN 'Appeals' then 'AP'
           WHEN 'Real Estate' then 'RE'
       END as areaoflaw
from matters
order by  Clientid;
```

Note that you need a column name after the case for the conditions to work.  That is what the `??` is for.

Comment: That case statement is wrong, though. It will not work.

Comment: Thank you so much.